# How to access multiple application yml from difference service on configure server(Spring)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-netflix

I have configured "configure-server" by fetching all configuration from gitlab repository.
Currently, when application(config-server) start it fetch all application properties in git repo.

In case, I have two client application A,B
which has difference application properties like

- aplication-a.yml
- aplication-b.yml

when application A start, I just only want configure-service fetch only application-a.yml from git repositry.

Here is application configure:

**Configure Server**

```
server:
  port: 9000
spring:
  application:
    name: CONFIG-SERVER
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://gitlab.com/mama/cloud-configure-server.git
          clone-on-start: true
          default-label: main
```

**Application A**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:9000
```

How to tell configure-service fetch only application-a.yml from git repository?
In case, I don't want to fetch all?

Thank you!!